# How to seed database with data from yaml file? Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, yaml

I need to fill my database with data from yaml file, which contains something like:

```
-Users:
------Users_nameship: 'First group'
------Members:
----------Name:'Jack'
```

etc.
And i need to use seeds.rb file
For now i make something like that:

```
    require 'yaml'

    seed_file = Rails.root.join('db', 'seeds.yml')
    @config = Hash.new(YAML::load_file(seed_file))
    @config.each do |key, values|
        values.each do |k,v|
            Project.create title:v
        end
    end
```

But its dont fill any cell in table. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Yaml files are used by fixtures for testing purposes. On the other hand, you can use db/seed.rb to populate your db with the following command:

```
rake db:seed
```

Check the following models:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
end
```

You could generate two groups with two users each with the following seed.rb file:

```
Group.create!([{name: "First group"}, {name: "Second group"}])

User.create!([{name: 'Jack', group_id: 1}, {name: 'Bob', group_id: 1}, {name: 'Robert', group_id: 2}, {name: 'John', group_id: 2}])
```